# realtime testing Google Analytics with javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to use the [Google's Javascript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples) api to check analytics for hits  fired by an automated test. The test fire hits like

- ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page':  '/vps/test/thanks.html',
                          'title': 'thanks', 
                          'dimension1': my_id });
- ga('send','event','button','click','nav buttons' });

On a page encoded using the [url builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) tool. What I'm trying to do is create a javascript function that waits for the realtime api (up to 10 seconds) and check if there is a hits has been sent for the source/medium combination in the encoded uri (http://example.com/default.php?utm_source=example&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=oxygen)

I've started with the [sample app](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples) and the [analytics samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/tree/master/samples/analytics/v3) - but so far made little headway with the real time api.client.analytics.data.ga.get

Comment: The realtime reporting API is in limited Beta, so you'd need to request access first. AFAIK the core reporting API does not work for realtime reports.

Comment: I cheked about that - once you fill in the reg form - you get a response that you will get whitelisted in 24 hours